# trying to find n in a list without using elem

Tags: haskell

I am trying to find `n` in a list of integers, out should be true if `n` is present without using the `elem` function.

```
present:: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
present n llist = [x | x <- llist, x == n]
```

Comment: In your code, you are creating a list, not a boolean. To obtain a boolean, you could test if the list is empty (or nonempty). One way could using the `null` function (or a `case of`).

Answer (score 3):

Your current `present` function doesn't type check: `[x | x <- llist, x == n]` results in a `[Integer]`, not a `Bool`.

As stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525817/trying-to-find-n-in-a-list-without-using-elem#comment133252703_75525817), you can determine whether `n` is in the list by checking whether the produced list is empty with `null`:

```
present :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
present n llist =  not $ null [x | x <- llist, x == n]
```

The list comprehension results in all the elements being equal to `n` from the original list. So, if the generated list is empty, the original list had no element whose value was `n`.

---

Another interesting approach that doesn't use `elem` and relies on explicit recursion:

```
present :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool
present _ [] = False -- base case
present n (x:xs) | x == n = True
                 | otherwise = present n xs
```

Here, the first element of the input list is checked against `n`. If it is equal to `n`, then `n` is present in the list, so the final result of `True` is produced. Otherwise, `present` is recursively called, and the input list passed to `present` becomes smaller with each recursion by one element until it finds `n` or eventually converges to the base case, the empty list, producing `False` in this case.